# Are there any normal animals in Pokemon universe?

Tags: pokemon, detective-pikachu

I watched **Pokémon Detective Pikachu** and I don't recall seeing any normal animals (like cats and dogs...). Do normal animals exist in the Pokemon universe (in movie or animation)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No normal animals were in the Pokemon Detective Pikachu movie.

[Normal animals do exist in the Pokemon universe](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world), but on a small scale. In the games, some people mention normal animals, X and Y have a restaurant that sells fish and butterflies in the background of some Pokemon battles, and Vespiquen uses bees in her moves Attack Order, Defend Order, and Heal Order. Many Pokemon are considered an "animal" Pokemon. For example Pikachu is the mouse Pokemon. For these descriptions to be made, said animal needs to exist in the universe (e.g. if mice didn't exist, no one would call Pikachu the mouse Pokemon).

They did also appear in the anime, mostly in the original series. Many of these occasions were fish, but worms, lobsters and a deer head were seen, amongst some others as well as talk of some animals. I've included an advertising picture of Slowpoke having fished a fish during the 1st generation of games.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that these animals are biologically Pokémon, but their size prevents them from really functioning as such and they're basically ignored by a world which, let's be honest, is pretty much based entirely on the handling of Pokémon?

Comment: Whilst potentially possible, I don't think it's the case. A deer head was seen in the anime, implying that deer exists. And deer are larger than many of the Pokemon. A deer would also likely function better in a battle than Magikarp, a fish that cannot even swim and commonly just knows Splash, a move that does nothing.

Comment: Magikarp does know how to swim. For exemple, the Magikarp Submarine of the team Rocket in season two of the anime is made to fit with the environement. Magikarp is weak at swimming and follow the stream but it does swim.

Comment: @MBorg we can also talk about the specification of some Pokeöon as Pikachu "the mouse Pokemon". How can they give a description of a Pokemon with a animal reference if there's not.

Comment: You're right; it can swim but weakly. I was thinking previously of the St Anne episode in season 1 where Jessie said Magikarp could not swim, but she was trying to get it to use Surf. I'll add the Pokedex entry references to my answer

Comment: @TinyDoowy The anime and games are separate canons. Regardless, it's quite clear from the games that Magikarp can swim (you catch them in the water). Flater: size cannot be the differentiator, as there are plenty of tiny Pokemon that are mere inches tall.

Comment: It is more likely this is a story telling device.  If we talked about/showed the animals, it would distract from the pocket monster's story.  Not everything about the world has to be told or seen.

Comment: I doubt that there was enough thought put into set elements like a deer head to guarantee consistent worldbuilding. It doesn't seem that there is any meaningful distinction between a Pokémon or any other type of animal in-universe, even in those few references. As for leaning on descriptions... I'm not sure there needs to be a "mouse" referent for Pikachu being the "mouse pokemon" any more than there needs to be an external "Pikachu" referent. Not to mention that Pokémon properties were designed for people in the real world, and so out-of-universe references are not surprising.

Answer (score -4):

There are no normal animals in Pokemon's make universe. The whole point of this is so that real animals don't need to be taken care of.

It's much simpler to store a pet in a mini pokeball than drag it around.

Comment: Since Pokémon aren't all taken care of either (wild pokémon exist); why do you assert that if animals were to exist, they would need to be taken care of?

Comment: Pokemon will use their powers to eat them off. Thanks